# Adyen - verify payment after successful transaction

Tags: php, adyen

I am currently using Web Drop-in.
After payment was successfully completed, it returns `sessionData` and `sessionResult`.

I want to redirect to a page with the values and verify/validate if the payment was done successfully.
I thought `sessionResult` should be able to validate the payment status with some types of reference number.
If I look at the API document as below, it seems like I need to pass `details`.
I am not sure if I am understanding the api docs.
How can we validate the payment?

```
$adyenService = new AdyenCheckout($adyenClient);
$result = $adyenService->paymentsDetails([
    'details' => ['redirectResult' => $sessionData]
]);
```

https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/Checkout/70/post/payments/details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the Web Drop-in with `/sessions` there is no need to make additional calls. If you look at [Session Flow vs Advanced Flow](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/additional-use-cases/) page you will see the differences:

- **session**: make one call (`/sessions`) and let the Drop-in take care of the payment execution
- **advanced**: make 3 API requests and take control of the payment flow.

In both cases, the final payment status is delivered to your application with [webhooks](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/webhooks/).

You should implement the endpoint that receives and processes the webhook payload: this contains all the information you need (status, pspReference, etc..).
Check out the [Adyen PHP sample](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-php-online-payments) app that includes a sample implementation of the webhook, using the PHP library.

This other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77195969/get-payment-details-by-pspreference) can also help to understand what needs to be done.