# Get payment details by pspReference

Tags: adyen

I'm trying to manage payout manually on Adyen platform.
To do that, I need to know if a payment has been settled, so the balance has been raised and I can payout that amount.
The POST payments API returns the pspReference, but I don't see the GET API to get the payment details.
How can I know its status?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There is no GET method to fetch the payment status but the final confirmation (state) is obtained with a combination of webhooks and settlement reporting.

**Payment authorisation**

The payment authorisation is delivered via webhooks.

You should implement (in whichever language you like) an endpoint that consumes the notification with payment status. The JSON payload looks like:

```
    
{
  "live": "false",
   "notificationItems": [
     {
      "NotificationRequestItem": {
       "additionalData": {
         “hmacSignature”: “ab1323…..”
       },
       "amount": {
         "currency": "EUR",
         "value": 1000
        },
        "eventCode": "AUTHORISATION",
        "eventDate": "2022-12-01T01:00:00+01:00",
        "merchantAccountCode": "YOUR_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT",
        "merchantReference": "YOUR_MERCHANT_REFERENCE",
        "paymentMethod": "ach",
        "pspReference": "YOUR_PSP_REFERENCE",
        "operations" : [],
        "success": "true"
      }
     }
   ]
}
```

The [adyen-examples](https://github.com/adyen-examples) repository contains samples in different languages that demonstrate how the webhook can be validated and processed, using the available [Adyen libraries](https://github.com/adyen).

**Payment settlement**

Payment settlement is performed in batches (typically involving a large number of payments per settlement).
The approach to this (reconciliation) is to download and process the [Settlement details report](https://docs.adyen.com/reporting/settlement-reconciliation/transaction-level/settlement-details-report/): it includes all payments that have been settled and paid out in one batch by Adyen.

It is possible to [automate](https://docs.adyen.com/reporting/automatically-get-reports/) the process by scheduling the report and configure the `REPORT_AVAILABLE` webhook to be notifed as soon as the report is available.

Comment: I already tried this way, but I didn't find a webhook called when the amount of the transaction is available in the balance.

Comment: Try to setup your webhook and set the url using `webhook.site`, make a payment and you should see the event being delivered. You can also trigger/test a webhook from the Customer Area (to verify the webhook payload is sent)

Comment: The problem is that there isn't a webhook triggered when a payment is settled.

Comment: I see, I missed this initially. I have edited the answer to make clear how to verify the payment authorisation (webhook) and payment settlement (reporting).

Comment: Great, I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot